# Alguien sabe porque el IDE de Java me retorna un error cuando convierto de String a GregorianCalendar

Tags: java

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String fechaN;
    System.out.println("Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento en el siguiento formato dd/mm/aaaa");
        try{    
            fechaN = br.readLine();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date d = sdf.parse(fechaN); 
            Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar ();
            fecha.setTime(d);
            if(fecha.get(fecha.MONTH) == fecha.JANUARY){
                System.out.println("El mes que escribiste fue Enero");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Es un mes distinto al que buscamos");
            }

        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error al leer datos");
        }
```

El problema recide en el codigo "Date d = sdf.parse(fechaN)" el parámetro en si pide un objeto de tipo Date pero he visto que muchos hacen el cambio de String a formato fecha de esta manera. La IDE logicamente me dice que lo castee a Tipo Date "Date d = (Date) sdf.parse(fechaN);" pero luego cuando lo ejecuto me lanza un error de ClassCastException. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Como ingresas la fecha por el teclado?

Comment: con el método readLine que invoco con el objeto br.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es si estas ingresando el texto de esta manera "11/04/207" o en algún otro formato?

Comment: Si claro, por eso resalto con el formato dd/mm/aaaa es decir 12/01/1997. Por poner un ejemplo.

Comment: checa en tus import si el import de tu date no esta en java.sql.Date, de ser así, ese es el error, agarras una clase que no es, debe ser java.util.Date

Comment: Perfecto ese era el error. Gracias amigo, vaya error que no había caído. Podrías decirme que diferencia hay con la librería sql?. Muchísimas Gracias :D

Comment: La librería de sql.Date es para dar fechas a sentencias de MySql, que es una base de datos, está extiende me parece de java.util.Date pero no son lo mismo, como dije una es para el manejo de base de datos y la otra en general. Si ya quedo la pregunta solucionada marcala como respuesta correcta por si alguien tiene la misma duda que tú, vea la solución

Comment: Ok gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checa en tus *import*, si el *import* de tu *date* no esta en `java.sql.Date`, de ser así, ese es el error, agarras una clase que no es, debe ser `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

El método `parse(String string)` de hecho devuelve un resultado de tipo `Date`, así si te sale una `ClassCastException`, revisa si importaste la clase `Date` que corresponde:

Existen dos clases `Date`.

- `java.util.Date` y
- `java.sql.Date`

Revisa tus imports, es muy probable que importaste `java.sql.Date`, así el cast de `java.util.Date` a la subclase `java.sql.Date` te falla con una `ClassCastException`. Si es así, cambia el import a `java.util.Date` y tu problema esta resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

ejemplo

```
try {
        String date = "11/12/1999";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date fechaSalida = format.parse(date);
        System.out.println(fechaSalida);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

espero te sirva!

Comment: Amigo, tu código le pasa lo mismo que ami. Da un error en la linea Date fechaSalida = format.parse(date);

Comment: si claro debes importar la libraria java.util.Date